# Microsoft graph api - Tenant not recognized

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created an app in App Registrations service in Azure portal to access Microsoft 365 graph api's.

I could create token using https://login.microsoftonline.com/570fa6c*************************f233/oauth2/v2.0/token , but when i tried [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserCounts(period='D7')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserCounts(period=%27D7%27)) using the token generated above, i am getting error - We do not recognize this tenant ID 570****************f233. Please double-check the tenant ID and try again

I have a free trial subscription

Could you please help, what am i missing here.

Thanks,

Neema

Comment: Thanks @RahulKumarShaw-MT , this step (Add Assignment->Select Member->Search you application and add it.) was missing in my setup . It is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested in my environment and it is working fine for me please use the below steps so you do not missed anything.

1. Created an application in Azure AD and given `Application -> Report.Read.All` ***API permission***.

[image]

2. Generated access token using postman with below Parameter passed in Body.

   ```
         https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token
   ```

[image]

3. Add an assignment to above AzureAD application with Reports reader Administrative roles in Microsoft Teams.

[image]

Add Assignment->Select Member->Search you application and add it.

[image]

4. Now finally run the getTeamsUserActivityUserCounts API with **Authorization** Key `Bearer {token}`.

For me showing the blackOuput as I have no activity for any users.

[image]